# estimate household expenditure pattern using a multivariate regression model, or other approach?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, random-forest, multivariate-regression

I am working on my school project, is about the study of household expenditure pattern using regression approach. Say that I having following linear ols regression model, where y is household expenditure.

$$
\begin{equation}
y= ε+B_0+ ∑_1^k B_k X_k 
 \end{equation}
$$

where $y$ is the dependent variable, $X$ are the independent variables, $B_0$ is the intercept term, $B_1,...,B_K$ are the regression coefficients for the independent variables and $ε$ is the error term.

And assume I have further information about household expenditure, which is expenditure pattern $(y_1,...y_k) $ such as food, transportation, and health, as denoted by equation below:

$$
\begin{equation}
y = y_1+y_2+...+y_k
\end{equation}
$$

I have code a python OLS regression and also a Random Forest regression using household expenditure as $y$, the dependent variable, and I obtained good r2 scores, about 0.84 for both model. Then, I started to further analyse the expenditure pattern, by developing multivariate OLS and Random Forest, however, the results are very bad, for both models. Below is how I build the model (for linear one).

```
# target_list is the list of expenditure pattern
y = data[target_list]
x = data.drop(columns = target_list, axis=1)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y,train_size = 0.8, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)

y_test = np.array(y_test)

lm = LinearRegression()

wrapper = MultiOutputRegressor(lm)

wrapper.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = wrapper.predict(x_test)

r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
print("r2: ",r2)

--------------------------------
r2:  0.12448338493025608
```

I have searched some papers about householold expenditure pattern, but I cannot find a paper that use the multivariate regression approach. Anyone have similar studies or suggestion about my topic? Should I give up multivariate regression approach on analysing the expenditure pattern? Appreciate for any guidance.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable approach. Here's one link to household level behavioral economics research. https://www.hbs.edu/ris/Publication%20Files/behavioral_household_finance_a3b33098-e0c7-40e0-bf2f-fa4ceb6e6d06.pdf

Comment: @MikeHunter tq for the paper, I will take a look on it.